# How to deal with exact precision in Java?

Tags: java, double, precision, bigdecimal

The requirement is to check whether a particular point lying in a 2D plane passes through a particular line or not.

The 2 initials points given are `(3,1)` and `(12, 3)`.
The slope of the line can be calculated as

```
(y2-y1) / (x2-x1)
```

The equation of the line can then be constructed with `y = mx + c`
where m is the slope and c is the constant.
The equation to represent the line comes out to be `2x + 3 = 9y`

So, to check whether the above line passes through the co-ordinate `(-6, -1)`, we simply check 
 2x + 3 = 9y

```
2x + 3 = 2(-6) + 3 = -12 + 3 = -9 = 9(-1) -> true
```

This is easy while dealing with a pen and paper.

However, the precision in java gets lost when the slope is calculated as (3-1)/(12-3) = 2/9

With Bigdecimal, while calculating the slope gives an exception

> java.lang.ArithmeticException: Non-terminating decimal expansion;  no exact representable decimal result.

And with double

```
    double slope = (double)(3-1)/(double)(12-3);  //0.2222222222222222
    // Putting (3,1) to get c
    double c = (double)(1) - (double)(slope * 3); //0.33333333333333337
    Hence the equation of the line is y = 0.2222222222222222(x) + 0.33333333333333337

    // to check whether (-6, -1) passes through the above line, put the x coordinate 
    double yCoordinate = 0.2222222222222222* (-6) + 0.33333333333333337;
```

yCoordinate comes out to be `-0.9999999999999999` which is not `-1`. So the result is false but the answer as calculated by plain mathematics is true. How can I get the expected result?

Comment: Check if the result is within a small delta of the expected result. And to stop the `ArithmeticException` being thrown by `BigDecimal` you have to use the appropriate [`MathContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/MathContext.html).

Comment: You could use a library providing fraction support, such as [Apache Commons Math](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/fraction.html)

Comment: What if you use org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(double expected, double actual, double delta)? (http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals(double,%20double,%20double))

Comment: You can use this Assert.assertEquals() to compare the result to a desired precision. E.g. `Assert.assertEquals(-1, -0.9999999999, 0.0001)`

Answer (score 0):

This is close enough to giving an exact value but is not the propper way

```
public double getExactValueDiv(double a,double b){
      double tmp = a/b;
      tmp=Math.round(tmp*1000000000)/1000000000
      return tmp;
}
```